Did Isaiah record any prophesies during the reign of Jotham?
At the start of Isaiah's famous vision in chapter six, we have the phrase, "In the year of King Uzziah’s death..." (Is. 6:1a). So the prophet's recorded vision happened at the end of Uzziah's ministry. The following chapter begins with these words, "Now it came about in the days of Ahaz, the son of Jotham, the son of Uzziah, king of Judah...Then the Lord said to Isaiah..." (Is. 7:1a, 3a). There seems to be at least a 16-year gap between the prophecy recorded in Isaiah 6 and the one recorded in Isaiah 7, spanning the reign of Jotham.
Yet, in Isaiah 1:1 it is written, "The vision of Isaiah the son of Amoz concerning Judah and Jerusalem, which he saw during the reigns of Uzziah, Jotham, Ahaz and Hezekiah, kings of Judah." There seems to be the possibility that some parts of Isaiah were prophesied and written during the days of Jotham.
Is this true? Are there sections of Isaiah that were prophesied and recorded during the days of Jotham, or did Isaiah just live during those days and had a 16-year gap in his ministry after his marvelous vision in Isaiah 6?

Don't forget the possinility that some of the prophesies of Isaiah were not recorded. He had contempories who needed to hear his message.

As the OP points out, Book of Isaiah begins with the following preface:

The vision which Isaiah, son of Amoz, saw concerning Judah and
Jerusalem in the days of Uzziah, Jotham, Ahaz and Hezekiah, kings of
Judah.

This clearly implies that Isiah's "vision" encompasses Jotham's reign but does not gives us a clear answer about specific prophecies. Following this prolog are five chapters of prophecy with little historical context.  Chapter six relates Isaiah's call in "the year that King Uzziah died."
Another important consideration is the fact that Jotham was co-regent or acting regent during the latter part of Uzziah's reign, because Uzziah had been struck with leprosy for usurping the role of the priests by offering incense in the temple.
2 Chronicles 26:21

King Uzziah remained a leper till the day he died. As a leper he lived
in a house apart, for he was excluded from the house of the Lord.
Therefore his son Jotham was master of the palace and ruled the people
of the land.

This seem to have been a period of fourteen years.
So the answer depends in part on when one thinks the reign of Jotham actually began. If the opening chapters contain early prophecies, they were almost certainly given during the period of Jotham's co-regency. For the period of Jotham's reign as sole king we may presume that Isaiah continued to prophesy but it is impossible to say with certainty which if any of his prophecies during this time were preserved.
